# Delphi Protocol Buffers?

Tags: delphi, protocol-buffers

Does anyone know of a project to do a Google Protocol Buffers implementation in Delphi?

Comment: Doesn't look that hard to have a go at it myself (yourself?), it's only the time (the time!!) I wish I had a few hours more per day.

Comment: Amen!  Was hoping to helpout and not start from scratch.

Comment: Protocol Buffers site: http://code.google.com/p/protobuf/  
protobuf-net is a .net implementation: http://code.google.com/p/protobuf-net/

Based on the above it must be more work than I first thought.
I would like a win32 or non .net version in Delphi.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This project contains the implementation of Protocol Buffers for Delphi. From the project was implemented limited functionality necessary for a specific project. At that time, I do not see any sense to transfer the whole project code.
http://sourceforge.net/projects/protobuf-delphi/

Comment: and has not been touched again since 2011. See below for the Fundamentals answer that appears to still be actively maintained.

Comment: Version 1.1 has been released in April 2013.

Answer (score 18):

Here:

Fundamentals Protocol Buffers 4.00.01 (10 Feb 2013)

Google Protocol Buffers

http://fundementals.sourceforge.net/dl.html

Comment: Appears to be actively maintained. +1 for this whereas the accepted answer appears to be frozen and never touched since 2011.

Answer (score 2):

You may be better off finding / making a C++ / Delphi bridge, rather than re-implementing Protocol Buffers.  The codebase is rather large.

Answer (score 1):

I found [another one](https://github.com/stijnsanders/DelphiProtocolBuffer) on the github. (developped from Feb.2014 to Jul.2016, as of June 2017)

It seems to have [preliminary proto3 support](https://github.com/stijnsanders/DelphiProtocolBuffer/commits/master).

<del>I didn't test yet, but it may be the best as of today.</del>

https://github.com/stijnsanders/DelphiProtocolBuffer

**EDIT:**
I tested this but it seems to be written in old delphi and not unicode ready.

I could compile the generator (using 10 Seattle), but compiled exe couldn't generate pas file :-(

**EDIT2:**

The code generator works just replacing TStream to TStreamReader/Writer.
I confirmed generator can convert recent [address book sample](https://github.com/google/protobuf/blob/master/examples/addressbook.proto).

```
diff --git a/ProtBufParse.pas b/ProtBufParse.pas
index f29d7c7..cdd734d 100644
--- a/ProtBufParse.pas
+++ b/ProtBufParse.pas
@@ -236,16 +236,13 @@ var

   procedure LoadCode;
   var
-    f:TFileStream;
+    sr:TStreamReader;
   begin
-    f:=TFileStream.Create(FilePath,fmOpenRead or fmShareDenyWrite);
+    sr:=TStreamReader.Create(FilePath, True{DetectBOM});
     try
-      //TODO: UTF-8? UTF-16?
-      CodeL:=f.Size;
-      SetLength(Code,CodeL);
-      if f.Read(Code[1],CodeL)<>CodeL then RaiseLastOSError;
+      Code := sr.ReadToEnd;
     finally
-      f.Free;
+      sr.Free;
     end;
   end;

diff --git a/dpbp.dpr b/dpbp.dpr
index 4049480..b6dab90 100644
--- a/dpbp.dpr
+++ b/dpbp.dpr
@@ -22,7 +22,7 @@ var
   p:TProtocolBufferParser;
   s,t,InputFN,OutputFN,RelPath:string;
   i,j,l,l1:integer;
-  f:TFileStream;
+  sw:TStreamWriter;
   fv:TProtocolBufferParserValue;
   ff:TProtocolBufferParserFlag;
   Flags:TProtocolBufferParserFlags;
@@ -134,11 +134,12 @@ begin

         writeln('Writing '+OutputFN);
         s:=p.GenerateUnit(Flags);
-        f:=TFileStream.Create(OutputFN,fmCreate);
+
+        sw:=TStreamWriter.Create(OutputFN,False,TEncoding.UTF8);
         try
-          f.Write(s[1],Length(s));
+          sw.Write(s);
         finally
-          f.Free;
+          sw.Free;
         end;

       finally
```

Answer (score -1):

I wonder what you think of using either [JSON](http://www.json.org/) or [BSON](http://code.google.com/p/pebongo/) seems like a work in progress) as a protocol.

Comment: It looks like protocol buffers are more feature rich since they allow for example optional elements, so it is more close to a XML+XSD/WSDL / SOAP protocol than to a serialization format